# SwitchPreferences calls multiple times the onPreferenceChange() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

According to [the Android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) I'm trying to implement preferences using Preference Fragments. In preferences.xml I declare:

```
<SwitchPreference 
        android:key="enable_wifi"
        android:title="Enable WiFi"
        />
```

And than in class thah extends PreferenceFragment in onCreate method I do:

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    mEnableWifi = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(enable_wifi);
    mEnableWiFi.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        Log.i(getClass().getName(), preference.getKey()
            + String.valueOf(newValue));
    }
}
```

And as a result I got when I clik on SwitchPreferene or Switch inside log shows

```
enable_wifi false
enable_wifi false
enable_wifi true
enable_wifi true
```

So that's why I suppose that listener is called multiple times. How to handle with it or fix it ?

Answer (score 12):

It is due to the bug in `SwitchPreference` implementation.

The callback `onPreferenceChange` is called:

- First time by [TwoStatePreference.onClick](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.java?av=f#66) method, which just updates the `SharedPreference`.
- Second time by the toggle state of the `Switch` widget. [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/preference/SwitchPreference.java?av=f#47) it is invoked.

Can't comment on the logic, but atleast the framework should have taken care of invoking `onPreferenceChange` callback only if there was a change in the state. So the responsibility lies with us. Use [SwitchPreference.isChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#isChecked()) method to check whether the state got changed.

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {     
    if(((SwitchPreference) preference).isChecked() != (Boolean) newValue) {
        // State got changed
        Log.i("Testing", preference.getKey() + " : " + String.valueOf(newValue));

        // If you don't want to save the preference change return false from this if block.
    }               
    return true;
}
```

Here is the callstack for your reference:

TwoStatePreference.onClick :

```
MainActivity$SettingsFragment$1.onPreferenceChange(Preference, Object) line: 45 
SwitchPreference(Preference).callChangeListener(Object) line: 895   
SwitchPreference(TwoStatePreference).onClick() line: 65 
SwitchPreference(Preference).performClick(PreferenceScreen) line: 950   
PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) line: 215    
ListView(AdapterView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 298   
ListView(AbsListView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 1100  
AbsListView$PerformClick.run() line: 2788   
AbsListView$1.run() line: 3463  
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 730   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 137
```

Switch widget toggle :

```
MainActivity$SettingsFragment$1.onPreferenceChange(Preference, Object) line: 45 
SwitchPreference(Preference).callChangeListener(Object) line: 895   
SwitchPreference$Listener.onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean) line: 47    
Switch(CompoundButton).setChecked(boolean) line: 126    
Switch.setChecked(boolean) line: 666    
SwitchPreference.onBindView(View) line: 106
```

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that the OP's code is lacking the return statement for `onPreferenceChange`.

Make sure you are invoking `return true;` at the end, so the preference is indeed changed.

If however the problem persists make a check inside of the preference change listener so it doesn't update unnecessarily:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    if (preference.isEnabled() != newValue) {
        // Do something on normal switch
        return true;
    } else {
        // Preference wasn't changed, do nothing and don't update it
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the problem was a missing `return` statement, would the code even compile? The log indicates that the code compiles just fine.

Comment: @Vikram If the return statement is missing, maybe something else is too? How can we tell where's the problem then? All we can do is guess then :-)

Comment: I absolutely agree with you - its hard to tell where the problem is. I only wanted to say that the code won't compile with a missing return statement. That was a nice catch though :))

Answer (score 0):

May be the fragment's object is being held in memory even when it is destroyed. So when the Fragment is created again the listener from the previous fragment is still there and the callback that you see are may be from two different listeners. In order to confirm the the call is indeed from two different listeners please try to print the object's toString method.

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
     Log.i(getClass().getName(), preference.getKey() + String.valueOf(newValue));
     Log.i(getClass().getName(), this.toString());
}
```

If you get different values for the toString then I think removing the listener in the fragment's onDestory might solve the problem for you.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mEnableWifi.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(null);
}
```